# How can I replace value at every 1000 line in Excel or Notepad++?

Tags: excel, notepad++

I have 100k records and I want to do query for those records in production ..

so for every 1000 line I want to replace comma with a string value (or `tablename.columnname` in ())

example

```
1000) '12345',
---
---
---
2000)'123431',
---
---
---
```

to replace to

```
1000) '12345')or tablename.columnname in (
---
---
---
2000)'123431')or tablename.columnname in (
---
---
---
```

Comment: For those who don't recognise the word, 1 lakh = 100,000 or 10^5.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a macro

`Macro` > `Start Recording`

`Search` > `Find` > `Find What` > `000)` and click `Find Next`

Change `Find What` to `,` and click `Find Next`.  Click `Close`

Click `delete` and enter your new text.

`Macro` > `Stop Recording`

Then execute it with

`Macro` > `Playback`  (Its short cut is `Control-Shift-P`)

Comment: i am asking at 1000 th line and 2000 th line boss??? macro will search 1000th and 2000th line ??

Comment: Your example indicated "line numbers"... ending in '000)'....  I suggested searching for that in the macro.